# css3 pie not working on dynamic css change

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, pie-chart

I'm using css3 PIE in order to create circle through border-radius(in IE8). It is working fine normally.
but when i'm trying to change the background color of circle, that element is turning into square.
my code looks like this.

```
    .menuIco {
        width:16px;
        height:16px;
        border-radius:8px;
        position:relative;
        z-index:101;
        background-color:#38B6E7;
    }

    .active .menuIco {
        background-color:#F1F1F1;
    }
```

my html looks like this..

```
    <div> <!-- i am adding .active class to this div using jquery -->
        <div class="menuIco"> </div>
    </div>
```

when i add active class to parent div(using Jquery dynamically) the menuIco (circle) should change its color. But the border-radius property is collapsing.

can anyone help me how to fix this!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using the htc instead of the js?

Comment: nope! im using js only

Answer (score 0):

Set your border-radius to `100%`.

Here's a [LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/oaLrm63u/) for you to see.

```
 .menuIco {
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        border-radius:100%;
        position:relative;
        z-index:101;
        background-color:#38B6E7;
    }
```

I have made the width and height to 100px so as to show it on a larger scale. (this can be resized as necessary)

**EDIT**

Depending on your browser, you should look to include the other prefixes, is shown in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/oaLrm63u/1/)

the border radius is defined by:

```
    -webkit-border-radius: 100%;
-moz-border-radius: 100%;
border-radius: 100%;
```

Comment: thanks for answering. but it's not working.. i'm adding that active class dynamically using jquery. after adding the border-radius is collapsing!!

Comment: Could you possibly provide a jsfiddle for me? As i'm not quite sure as to why this is failing, apart from not including other prefixes for multi-browser support (shown in edit).

Comment: jsfiddle doesnt works in IE8!! so how can i show u demo??

border-radius is collapsing in IE8 , in other browsers it is working fine!!

Comment: Please refer to [this article](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/css3-border-radius-in-internet-explorer/) which supports IE7/8

Comment: FYI, i am implementing in the same methos. but when i am changing the css dynamically after loading the page in IE8 it is collapsing!!! it is behaving differently... i think the problem is with PIE.js it is not triggering after dynamic css change i guess. i think you didnt understand the problem clearly.